# Visual Studio: referenced dll file on disk resets after adding it into resources

Tags: .net, visual-studio, filereference

I want add file reference in assembly in Visual Studio to some file on the hard disk. And also i want place the file in the resources of the project. 
But after i added file into resources, 
Visual Studio replace my own file reference to resources directory. 
E.g. i added reference *C:/Dir/myfile.dll*, Visual Studio replace it with *MyProject/Resources/myfile.dll*. I need my assembly looking for file at *C:/Dir/* location. Obviously, assembly search the file in startup directory first, and crashing if can not find it.
Can I forced set my assembly searching order of referenced files?

Comment: Maybe you can try to rename the resource dll as a workaround :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik What the nice and simple solution) i'll check it. Thanks.

Comment: If that helps I can create an answer that you can accept :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Visual Studio can find side-part assembly in that way, and not change reference added by me. But it copy this assembly in startup folder now) It wasn't exactly what i need, and maybe my question was not correct. I need use absolute path in XAML xmlns definitions. Not shure it is possible... But your answer helped me. Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason you need the dll in resources in the first place? Maybe there is a better solution?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik i need check if dll is presented on local machine, and if not, copy the dll from resources to hdd. And then use it in my app.

Comment: And i want place dll in certain location, not into app startup directory.

Comment: And why does app startup does not work?

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik It's works, but i need use exact file location on the harddisk.

Comment: I understood that, I mean why is that you need to use exact file location? If you can just use it ordinary way then it'll always be in your bin folder. What is the reason for doing exact location? (I am asking since there can be a better solution perhaps to the original problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik users run portable application from desktop often. I just not like when some app creates different files on desktop. It's more nice when app creates additional files in the some hidden location, e.g. in temp directory. Imho) Do you know more acceptable solution?

Comment: Sorry, not an expert on portable applications :) I suppose just a shortcut won't cut it. But I suppose the bin folder should be somewhere not on desktop. Anyway I guess I cannot help you more, sorry :)

Comment: I know that my app will run from user desktop.

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Thank you! Your advice will the part of my final solution)

Comment: Then I'll add it as an answer and you can upvote it and accept if you don't get a better answer :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik Ok. I'm new at this site. How can i do this? I'm using mobile app.

Comment: Added an answer. If you accept it and upvote then both me and you will get some score :)

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik I accepted, but can't vote. My rating is too low.

Comment: np :) glad I could help, just not too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you as a workaround to rename the file that you put in the resource, that should at least stop overriding your library.